Is this an example of an infinite regress, an infinite loop, or both?
Consider a logician who thinks the following thought: whatever I assume or expect is false or will never happen. But then the logician thinks this itself is an assumption, so it will not happen either. So it will happen. But again that too an assumption...
So this seems to go on forever. But what I want to know is: whether this argument pattern is an infinite loop which rotates forever or a regress which will go on forever. Assumptions becoming assumptions, etc. Or could it be both? What is the best (or a good) way to analyze this?

You describte this negativity bias as a "fixed thought". Better than further search for a suitable name or description is to ask yourself: What can I do to get rid of it?

The question seems to me more like a question about how to apply recursion in modal logic, given the premiss p: '∀x: B(x) → ¬x'. So, then the question is what can be derived from 'B(p)' when the premisse is applied to itself. It seems to me that in (most? all?) modal logics (of belief) you can then derive '∃x: B(x) ∧  ¬x' which is a kind of contradiction (an variant of Moore's paradox "I believe it rains, but it's not raining"). @KristianBerry you know more about modal logics - what do you think?

@Prathamesh - Both in logic and in game theory (the theory of meta-games) we can usually show that infinite loops will not substantially change the derivable outcomes. For instance, for 2-person games we can prove that it's sufficient to consider "what should I do when he knows what I will do when he does x" -- this may seem to lead to an infinite loop, but after two steps the relevant outcomes cannot change anymore. In logic, there is an analogous situation. (In "infinite loops" during computations, the loop is also caused by falling into a repeated pattern.)

@Prathamesh - Perhaps https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doxastic_logic could clear up some of your question(s).

I have made some significant edits to the question in order to have it be re-opened. I hope these edits are ok with you @prathamesh. Considering for instance Smullyan's article, the question does have logical/philosophical relevance, so it's a pity if it would remain closed.

It might just be that the first assumption ("whatever I assume or expect is false or will never happen.") is false. It doesn't imply that any other assumption will be.


I have this thought: like, whatever I assume or expect will never happen. But then I think this itself is an assumption, so it will not happen either. So it will happen. But again it's too an assumption...

You ask whether your argument pattern is an infinite loop or infinite regress. You also seem to express some wonder or confusion, an implicit question whether those thoughts are self-contradictory or stable. This is a delightful question and you may find an answer in Raymond Smullyan's equally delightful essay Logicians who reason about themselves (see also the wiki article about Doxastic logic which studies various ways of logical reasoning with "belief".)
First of all, if what you describe "I have this thought ..." refers to an actual psychological predicament, then you may be describing an idee fixe -- an obsessive, often unpleasant, recurring thought. If so, that may be a psychological problem about which philosophers don't have much to say.
Second, what you describe is similar to the psychological (and game-theoretical) scenario of a so-called self-fullfilling prophecy. There are positive (pleasant) and negative (unpleasant) variants of this ("the power of positive thinking" versus "doomerism" or "fatalism"). Philosophy doesn't have much to say about that either, though traditionally this was a philosophical problem. For instance we can see the problem of fatalism explicitly conceptualized in the arguments against believing in fate in the classical Chinese philosophy of Mozi, arguments that are based on common sense and are still relevant. But I will also leave that aside.
Your argument starts with the following premiss

Whatever I assume or expect will never happen.

The words "assume", "expect" and "believe" in this context are all pretty much equivalent. So I propose to reformulate this as

Whatever I believe (to happen) will never happen

In symbols (see the wikipedia link above) this becomes

(1) ∀p: p → ¬p

This says that for any proposition p, if the subject believes p, then p is false. The operator  acts on propositions and has an implicit reference (index) that refers to the subject that has the belief (I'm leaving this index out, since we are only considering one particular subject, 'you'). In this case, (1) says that the subject only believes what happen to be falsehoods. (This ignores the temporal aspect of your question, which should be fine since we can restrict the beliefs to beliefs about the future. Implicitly you were already ingoring this when you moved from (1) to (2) below.) I will call (1) "the pessimistic assumption".
Then you continue...

But then I think this itself is an assumption, so ...

This means you become aware of (1) and become aware that you believe (1), so we then have

(2) ((1))

which is equivalent to

(2') (∀q: q → ¬q)

if we assume that you are a reflexive reasoner (see the wiki article), so that we may substitute the full proposition (the intensional meaning) for the name of the proposition (as we did in (2) and (3)). (This assumption is actually kind of tricky and not unproblematic although we do this all the time in informal reasoning.) I will call (2') "the reflexive pessimistic assumption".
You then realize that (2') expresses a particular belief, so it can be plugged into (1). So, from (1), setting p ≡ (2') we derive,

(3)  ((2')) → ¬(2')
(3') (∀q: q → ¬q) → ¬(∀q: q → ¬q)

But actually, since you do believe (1), the antecedent of (3') is true. So, from (2') and (3') we can derive

(4) ¬(∀q: q → ¬q)

Then if you are a type 1 reasoner (see wiki), meaning if you use the classical propositional logic, you can derive

(5)   ∃q: ¬(q → ¬q)
(5')  ∃q: ¬(¬q ∨ ¬q)
(5'') ∃q: q ∧ q

This is not remarkable by itself. It just says that the subject has a belief that happens to be true. But it's remarkable in so far that it contradicts (1)...
We actually didn't have to derive anything further from (4), since (4) itself is the negation of (1). So, we've achieved a reductio ad absurdum.
In conclusion, I think this means an infinite regress or infinite loop doesn't really apply to this (it doesn't achieve lift off as it were). If my analysis is correct, then from the basic premisses (1) and (2), we can derive that (1) is not the case. We derive this using the implicit other assumptions that I mentioned. This further implies that either (1) is false and/or (2) is false. So, if you are a stable and consistent reasoner you either can not believe that (1) (the pessimistic assumption) and/or you can not believe that you believe (1) (the reflexive pessimistic assumption).
Note that you implicitly also seem to be assuming the principle of normal reasoners '∀p: p → p' (modal axiom 4). This principle by itself does set up infinite sequences, since for any a we can then derive, a, a, a, ... But those should be innocuous. (I think they don't really give you more power, they may only restrict what you can derive. Psychologically they, of course, also quickly lose sense.) In this case we could go from (4) to ((4))A and plug that in again into (1), but after that round, we will basically be back to where we started -- this is what I meant by saying that the infinite regress doesn't achieve lift off. Formally, you could consider an infinite sequence of statements but those would always keep toggling between (1) and its negation (4), just like (in classical logic) the sequence p, ¬p, ¬¬p, ¬¬¬p, ¬¬¬¬p, ... keeps toggling between p and ¬p.

A. Note that going from from (4) to ((4)) (or from (1) to (2) above) can not be simply justified by assuming ∀p: p → p. It's a move that is only justified by that principle if you as it were self-reflect your whole reasoning again. In general it's not warranted to assume ∀p: p → p (which informally says something like "I know everything").

In my judgment one needs an intuitive or dramatic concept, such as Ouroboros, to know logic and decode meaning of symbols! See https://recursivelyrecursive.wordpress.com/2010/02/18/ouroboros/ The Ouroboros is a mythical serpent in the form of a circle, swallowing its own tail and thereby symbolising infinity or eternity.  Feeding on itself with no need of any other food, it is re-creating itself in a never-ending circularity. Self is a closed loop where I experience my desires, decisions, and muscle actions as a proximate cause of my own sensory-perceptions. But self is not the sole cause.

Hugh Gibbons, my professor for Legal Philosophy, describes the will using and I-statment: I am the cause of desired perceptions.
Baruch Spinoza describes an affect, or emotion, as a feeling of desire, pleasure, or pain accompanied by an idea of its cause. The sources and causes of desire are manifold and impossible to articulate. But the causes of pleasure or pain, and ideas of cause in general, Spinoza describes as self, others, natural events, and God as the abstract or ultimate source of cause.
I modified Hugh's concept of will as follows. In this context of self-perception Events or Outcomes have several attributes:

attributes that I can cause;
attributes that I cannot cause;
attributes that I desire to experience;
attributes that I do not desire to experience.

This means sometimes I am the cause of desired experience, so I desire the perception, and I cause it to happen. For example, I desire to type this sentence, and my memories enable my muscles to type the sentence without much effort. Sometimes I desire to cause specific perceptions but instead I cause some events or outcomes that I don't desire. And, of course, other people and reality cause events that I perceive and which I cannot control.
Sometimes I suffer from mental patterns that I call residual pain or persistent pain. Usually these are emotions or affects as described by Baruch Spinoza: a feeling of desire, pleasure, or pain accompanied by an idea of its cause. During early life one has little capacity to cause desired perceptions and yet might blame the self for painful events. The self would naturally judge as "not good enough" to stop such pain. We call this shame. The self wants to end the pain, and might blame the self for inability to end the pain, we call this guilt. I think every mammal can become enmeshed in a pattern of suffering from persistent residual pain but humans have the capacity to repent, or think again, and dissolve some modes of residual pain by improving our comprehension of how we experience persistent pleasure or pain.
